# Java dynamic list in while(true) loop

Tags: java

I have a list with objects and I need to iterate thru the list forever while items are getting removed or getting added. This all should happen in a runnable thread. What I want is that the iterating never stops while still being able to add new objects to it, and remove the finished ones.

- I want to add new objects from outside from the while(true) thread.
- I want to remove items in the while(true) thread.
- It's like an FIFO but Dynamic. Or like an queue which never stops.
- If the list is empty, it has to wait for new objects.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: You want a queue? We have queues.

Comment: Use a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). It will block

Comment: Agree with Johannes, use LinkedBlockingQueue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the Producer / Consumer pattern.  Java has thread safe ways to achieve this.  The easiest would be to use `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<E>`

The way to use it is to share the BlockingQueue between a Consumer (thread) and one or more Producer threads.  The Consumer blocks with the method `E Queue.take()`.  The clients add to the Queue with method `Queue.offer(E)`.

First create the BlockingQueue:

```
BlockingQueue<MyObject> myQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<MyObject>(int capacity);
```

The server thread will look something like this:

```
    BlockingQueue<MyObject> myQueue;
    // A constructor which receives the BlockingQueue object

    // Main Loop
    boolean isInterrupted = false;

    while(!isInterrupted) {
        try {
            MyObject object = myQueue.take();   // Will block
            // Process object
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            isInterrupted = true;
        }
    }
```

And for each producer thread, pass the BlockingQueue object to each, and use:

```
BlockingQueue<MyObject> myQueue;
// A constructor which receives the BlockingQueue object

// Create MyObjects
myQueue.offer(myObject);   // Will add to the queue
```

There is the concept of a queue capacity.  If the producers add too quickly queue may reach capacity.  An offer can fail in this case.  See the javadoc [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) for full details